Why doesn't iostat show any I/Os for 2 mins?
I'm logging iostat every second (and writing to /tmp to avoid interference with any Disk) with the following command:
iostat -ymtxz -p sda,sdb,sdc,sdd,sde 1 270000 
During a time window when the write load on the system is high, I see a window of darkness in the iostat output (notice timestamps between 11:33:11 and 11:35:28), where there seems to be no writes to the disk:

08/15/2024 11:33:06 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          11.48    0.06    3.36   82.30    0.00    2.79

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s
sda             35.00      1.55     0.00   0.00 3306.49    45.49   48.00      2.83   119.00  71.26 4160.54    60.33    0.00      0.00     0.00
sda1            35.00      1.55     0.00   0.00 3306.49    45.49   48.00      2.83   119.00  71.26 4160.54    60.33    0.00      0.00     0.00
sdb              8.00      1.25     0.00   0.00 1242.25   160.50   13.00      1.43    98.00  88.29  452.85   112.31    0.00      0.00     0.00
sdb1             8.00      1.25     0.00   0.00 1242.25   160.50   13.00      1.43    98.00  88.29  452.85   112.31    0.00      0.00     0.00


08/15/2024 11:33:07 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           3.28    0.00    1.64   89.15    0.00    5.93

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s
sda             12.00      0.77     0.00   0.00  613.25    65.33    1.00      0.00     2.00  66.67  506.00     4.00    0.00      0.00     0.00
sda1            12.00      0.77     0.00   0.00  613.25    65.33    1.00      0.00     2.00  66.67  506.00     4.00    0.00      0.00     0.00
sdb              1.00      0.12     0.00   0.00  262.00   128.00    5.00      2.12     0.00   0.00  535.20   435.20    0.00      0.00     0.00
sdb1             1.00      0.12     0.00   0.00  263.00   128.00    5.00      2.12     0.00   0.00  535.20   435.20    0.00      0.00     0.00


08/15/2024 11:33:08 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           7.31    0.00    1.89   84.75    0.00    6.05

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s


08/15/2024 11:33:09 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           6.27    0.00    6.08   82.77    0.00    4.88

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s

08/15/2024 11:33:10 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.08    0.00    1.39   88.40    0.00    8.13

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s
sda             14.00      0.73     0.00   0.00 4152.86    53.71   40.00      1.14    46.00  53.49 3798.95    29.10    0.00      0.00     0.00
sda1            14.00      0.73     0.00   0.00 4152.86    53.71   40.00      1.14    46.00  53.49 3798.95    29.10    0.00      0.00     0.00
sdb              2.00      0.01     0.00   0.00  166.00     4.00   37.00     15.99     1.00   2.63 2589.16   442.59    0.00      0.00     0.00
sdb1             2.00      0.01     0.00   0.00  165.50     4.00   37.00     15.99     1.00   2.63 2589.16   442.59    0.00      0.00     0.00


08/15/2024 11:33:11 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.20    0.00    2.51   85.04    0.00   10.25

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s


08/15/2024 11:33:12 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           3.15    0.00    1.38   89.30    0.00    6.17

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s


08/15/2024 11:33:13 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           4.99    0.00    1.07   93.62    0.00    0.32

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s


....
<more empty rows as above rows>
....

08/15/2024 11:35:26 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.19    0.00    0.38   99.43    0.00    0.00

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s


08/15/2024 11:35:27 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.32    0.00    0.63   99.05    0.00    0.00

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s


08/15/2024 11:35:28 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.32    0.00    0.57   99.12    0.00    0.00

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s


08/15/2024 11:35:29 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           3.22    0.00    2.40   94.38    0.00    0.00

Device            r/s     rMB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dMB/s   drqm/s
sda             13.00      0.75     0.00   0.00 142574.38    58.77   50.00      1.66     0.00   0.00 142970.86    33.92    0.00      0.00     0
sda1            13.00      0.75     0.00   0.00 142574.38    58.77   50.00      1.66     0.00   0.00 142970.86    33.92    0.00      0.00     0
sdb              0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00   26.00     12.50     0.00   0.00 141668.50   492.46    0.00      0.00     0.0
sdb1             0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00   26.00     12.50     0.00   0.00 141668.50   492.46    0.00      0.00     0.0

This is on a P20 Azure Premium SSD, with peak throughput of 150 MB/s and we are not near that (nor do we seem throttled on IOPS). But iostat seems to suggest that kernel is not issuing any writes to the disks (sda and sdb are both SSDs)
I suspected Dirty page write backs by the kernel to be the cause which was blocking I/Os from my process (which was my original problem: my process - a DB, was complaining about disk writes not going through for over a minute), but on cross checking the dirty pages from /proc/vmstat, I see the dirty page numbers are constantly changing:
2024-08-15 11:33:11
nr_dirty 793633
nr_writeback 46824
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 962418
nr_dirty_background_threshold 480621

2024-08-15 11:33:12
nr_dirty 795366
nr_writeback 46940
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 963980
nr_dirty_background_threshold 481401

2024-08-15 11:33:13
nr_dirty 797412
nr_writeback 46945
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 965055
nr_dirty_background_threshold 481938

2024-08-15 11:33:14
nr_dirty 799111
nr_writeback 46945
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 967765
nr_dirty_background_threshold 483292

2024-08-15 11:33:15
nr_dirty 801237
nr_writeback 46945
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 968222
nr_dirty_background_threshold 483520

..
...
....


2024-08-15 11:33:33
nr_dirty 812035
nr_writeback 46954
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 977632
nr_dirty_background_threshold 488219

2024-08-15 11:33:34
nr_dirty 812051
nr_writeback 46954
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 977850
nr_dirty_background_threshold 488328

2024-08-15 11:33:35
nr_dirty 812064
nr_writeback 46954
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 977434
nr_dirty_background_threshold 488120

.
..
...

2024-08-15 11:35:23
nr_dirty 813683
nr_writeback 46969
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 974575
nr_dirty_background_threshold 486692

2024-08-15 11:35:24
nr_dirty 813687
nr_writeback 46969
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 974662
nr_dirty_background_threshold 486736

2024-08-15 11:35:25
nr_dirty 813687
nr_writeback 46969
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 974256
nr_dirty_background_threshold 486533

2024-08-15 11:35:26
nr_dirty 813688
nr_writeback 46969
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 974254
nr_dirty_background_threshold 486532

2024-08-15 11:35:27
nr_dirty 813689
nr_writeback 46969
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 974233
nr_dirty_background_threshold 486522

2024-08-15 11:35:28
nr_dirty 813692
nr_writeback 46969
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 974233
nr_dirty_background_threshold 486521

2024-08-15 11:35:29
nr_dirty 814200
nr_writeback 39304
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 973401
nr_dirty_background_threshold 486106

2024-08-15 11:35:30
nr_dirty 797184
nr_writeback 7870
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 969343
nr_dirty_background_threshold 484079

2024-08-15 11:35:31
nr_dirty 742564
nr_writeback 19588
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 959952
nr_dirty_background_threshold 479390

2024-08-15 11:35:32
nr_dirty 713285
nr_writeback 6728
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 969869
nr_dirty_background_threshold 484342

2024-08-15 11:35:33
nr_dirty 704353
nr_writeback 18921
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 964665
nr_dirty_background_threshold 481743


I see that the nr_dirty hasn't crossed nr_dirty_threshold (which would possibly cause kernel to block writes from processes).
I see that the nr_writeback is high - which could be explained by high number of dirty pages, so kernel might be trying to flush as many dirty pages to disk in the background (possibly overloading the disk), but shouldn't that reflect in iostat output? Why is iostat output empty during this long duration of over 2 minutes?
Other details: I'm on Ubuntu, using ext4 and using an lvm.
